Unity VR でタイマーを開始・停止できるようにしたい
UnityでVRプロジェクトを開発しており、VRハンドでボタンを押すとタイマーが開始・停止されるようにしたいと考えています。OVRCameraRigのRightHandでStartボタンを押すとタイマーを開始し、別のボタンでタイマーを停止するようにしたいです。
以下がタイマーのスクリプトです：
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    public float startTime;
    public bool timerActive = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (timerActive)
        {
            float time = Time.time - startTime;
            string minutes = ((int)time / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (time % 60).ToString("f1");
            timerText.text = "Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        timerActive = true;
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        timerActive = false;
    }
}

StartTimer()とStopTimer()をボタンに紐付けるために、以下のVRButtonスクリプトを使用しています：
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class VRButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent onClick;
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        onClick.Invoke();
    }
}

ハンドとボタンの両方にBoxColliderを追加し、IsTriggerにチェックを入れています。
問題点:
Startボタンを押すと、タイマーが開始されません。
また、timerActiveをtrueの状態で開始すると、正しくタイマーは起動します。
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
        onClick.Invoke();
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}

のように設定してみたところ，問題なくキューブは生成されました．
VRハンドでタイマーを確実に開始・停止させるためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

OVRCameraRig を使用しているということは、Meta Quest での開発ですよね？
さらに OVRCameraRig を使用しているということは、Meta XR SDK を使用していますよね？
Meta XR SDK では、ハンド / コントローラーのインタラクションがサポートされているので、こちらの機能を利用して開発することが良いかと思います。
Meta XR SDK では、ハンドの指で物体をつつく操作を Poke と表現しています。
以下、Meta XR SDK を使用して、Poke 操作でボタンに触れて、イベントを受信、処理を実行する手順を説明します。
念のためですが、Meta XR SDK セットアップの手順は以下にあります。

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-package-manager/

どれを選択して良いか不明な場合は、Meta XR All-in-One SDK をインストールください。すべての Meta XR SDK を一括でインストールできます。
コントローラー / ハンドへの PokeInteractor の追加
以下の「ハンドPokeインタラクターの追加」もしくは、「コントローラーPokeインタラクターの追加」を参照し、PokeInteractor を追加します。

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-isdk-create-poke-interactions/

もしくは、コントローラー ハンドを使用している場合は、以下の「コントローラーハンドのインタラクション設定」を参照ください。

https://zenn.dev/meson/articles/quest-buildingblocks-interaction

対象オブジェクトへの PokeInteractable の追加
先のサイトの「PokeインタラクタブルをGameObjectに追加する」の手順を実行しても良いですが、Meta XR SDK の BuldingBlock を使用すると、これらの手順を省くことができます。
Unity のメニュー [Oculus] - [Tools] - [Building Blocks] - [Poke Interaction] - [Add Block to current scene] を選択すると、ヒエラルキーに [[BuildingBlock] Poke Interaction] が追加されます。
スタートボタン、ストップボタン用に 2 つ Poke Interaction を追加し、適当な座標に配置してください。
ここで、一度、プログラムを実行し、ハンドで配置したオブジェクトに触れて、色が変わることを確認してください。

Poke で選択状態が検知されたら緑色になります。
色に変更がなければ、PokeInteractor の設定が正しく行われていないと思われますので、先の手順に戻って正しく設定を完了してください。
タイマー表示ロジックの実装
ヒエラルキーに、TimerView という空のオブジェクトを追加します。
経過時間表示用に TextMesh をこのオブジェクト以下に追加します。
さらに、以下のスクリプトをアタッチします。
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimerViewManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshPro TextMesh;    

    private System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    private void Start()
    {
        this.TextMesh.text = "00:00:00";
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
        {
            this.TextMesh.text = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff");
        }
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}

インスペクターから、このスクリプトのプロパティ TextMesh へ経過時間表示用に作成した TextMesh を設定してください。
ボタン選択イベントの受信
どこに設定しても良いのですが、今回は、TimerView オブジェクトへイベントの受信を設定します。
インスペクターから、TimerView オブジェクトへ InteractableUnityEventWrapper を「二つ」アタッチします。

次に、一方の[InteractableUnityEventWrapper] スクリプトの [InteractableView] プロパティへヒエラルキーから一方の [[BuildingBlock] Poke Interaction] をドラッグし設定。

もう一方の[InteractableUnityEventWrapper] スクリプトの [InteractableView] プロパティへヒエラルキーからもう一方の [[BuildingBlock] Poke Interaction] をドラッグし設定。
これで、Poke 時のイベントが受信できるようになりました。
イベント受信時の処理の起動
最後に、Poke された際の Select イベント発火時に、TimerViewManager.StartTimer、TimerViewManager.StopTimer を実行するようにします。
インスペクターから、一方の [InteractableUnityEventWrapper] - [When Select()] - [+] を選択。
[None (Object)] と表示されている個所へ、ヒエラルキーから、TimerView をドラッグして設定。
[No Function] と表示されている個所から、TimerViewManager.StartTimer() を選択します。

もう一方の [InteractableUnityEventWrapper] でも同様の手順を実施し、TimerViewManager.StopTimer() 選択します。
プログラムの実行
プログラムを実行して動作を確認します。
以下は、実行時のキャプチャーです。

ここにアップロードできるファイル制限のため動画のフレームを少なくしているので、かなりコマ落ちしていますが、Poke によるイベントの発火、処理の実行が正しく動作していることが分かります。
また、ちょっとわかりにくいかもしれませんが、ボタンを押したときにボタンがへこむ表現もできています。これは、PokeInteractable で提供されているもので、BuildingBlock の Poke Interaction でも PokeInteractable が利用されているためこのような表現ができます。
Poke については、以下に詳しく説明されています。

https://xrdnk.hateblo.jp/entry/interaction_sdk_poke

独自に機能を作りこんでいくことも良いかとは思いますが、デバイスで提供されている SDK を利用した方が、デバイスを使ってやりたいこと、後になって必要となる機能、デバイス特有の機能がライブラリとしてあらかじめ用意されており、高度な機能を短時間で実装できると考えています。
確かに習熟コストはかかると思いますが、Meta Quest 開発者は多く、Web 上でも多くの情報があります。今回の私の回答においても開発者の方々が公開されている情報に助けられました。
SDK でどのようなことができるかは、以下 Meta XR Interaction SDK OVR Samples を確認すると良いと思います。

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/meta-xr-interaction-sdk-ovr-samples-268521


ありがとうございます．今回OVRを用いず，XROriginを使用しております．そのため，できる限りMetaQuestの機能に依存せずに実装を進めたいと考えています．

質問文中に「OVRCameraRig」とありますが、これは誤りでしょうか？
また、「XROrigin」ということは、「XR Interaction Toolkit」を使用しているというでしょうか？

おっしゃる通りです．また，提示していただいた内容で実装ができました．ありがとうございます．

対応案１．コライダーの設定の確認
タイマーが開始されない問題は、OnTriggerEnter メソッドが期待通りに呼び出されていない可能性が高いです。
（OnTriggerEnterはUnityで使用されるメソッドで、コライダー（Collider）がトリガーとして設定された別のコライダーと接触すると自動的に呼び出されます。このメソッドは、物理的な衝突を検出するためではなく、オブジェクトが特定の領域に入った瞬間を検出するために使用されます。）
まず、コライダー（BoxCollider）の設定が適切であることを確認してください。

VRハンドとボタンのサイズ: コライダーが小さすぎると、正しくトリガーされないことがあります。サイズが適切か確認し、必要であれば調整してください。
レイヤーの設定: ハンドとボタンが同じレイヤーに属しているか、または互いに影響を受けるようにレイヤーが設定されているかを確認してください。

対応案２．コライダーではなくOVRInputを実行の起点にする
コライダーの領域判定のような不安定な起動方法ではなく、OVRInputでボタンの押下状態をチェックするのはどうでしょうか？
OnTriggerEnter を使用する代わりに、タイマーの開始・停止をより確実に実行するための別の方法として、Oculus Integration SDK の入力システムを直接使用することを検討することができます。これにより、ハンドコントローラーのボタンが押されたときに直接イベントを呼び出すことが可能になります。
OVRInputを使用する方法
Oculus Integration SDK の OVRInput クラスを使用して、コントローラーのボタンの状態を直接検出し、それに基づいてタイマーを制御することができます。これは、コントローラーに物理的なボタンを使用してタイマーを制御する直感的で確実な方法です。
スクリプトの例
以下は OVRInput を使用してタイマーを制御するための基本的なスクリプト例です：
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;
    private bool timerActive = false;

    void Update()
    {
        // コントローラーのボタンをチェック
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.One, OVRInput.Controller.RTouch))
        {
            if (!timerActive)
            {
                StartTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                StopTimer();
            }
        }

        // タイマーがアクティブなら更新
        if (timerActive)
        {
            float time = Time.time - startTime;
            string minutes = ((int)time / 60).ToString();
            string seconds = (time % 60).ToString("f2");
            timerText.text = "Time: " + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
    }

    void StartTimer()
    {
        timerActive = true;
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    void StopTimer()
    {
        timerActive = false;
    }
}

このスクリプトでは、Update メソッド内で OVRInput.GetDown() を使用して、右手のコントローラーの「One」ボタン（通常はAボタン）が押されたかどうかを毎フレームチェックしています。ボタンが押されたとき、タイマーが非アクティブなら開始し、アクティブなら停止します。
このアプローチの利点

直接的: ボタンの入力は直接的で、物理的なフィードバックもあるため、ユーザーにとってわかりやすい。
確実性: 物理ボタンの状態を直接読み取るため、コライダーの問題による不具合の影響を受けません。
カスタマイズしやすい: ボタンの割り当てや機能の変更が容易です。

この方法を使用すれば、コライダーやトリガーゾーンに依存することなく、より直接的かつ確実にタイマーを制御することが可能です。
